# randomly subsample once every month pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, random, sampling

I have the following dataframe.

```
data = {'bid':['23243', '23243', '23243', '12145', '12145', '12145', '12145'],
        'lid':['54346786', '23435687', '23218987', '43454432', '21113567', '54789876', '22898721'],
        'date':['2021-08-11','2021-08-12','2021-09-17','2021-05-02','2021-05-11','2021-05-20','2021-08-13'],
        'val1':[44,34,54,76,89,33,27],
        'val2':[11,55,43,89,76,44,88]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

What I am looking for is to randomly pick a `lid` per month for the `bid` column, and maintain a count of past instances until the point of the random sample, something similar to this:

[image]

I can think of separating the year and months into different columns and then apply pd.groupby on the bid, year and month with the pd.Series.sample function, but there must be a better way of doing it.

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: What dou you mean by 'randomly pick a lid per month'. Do you want to pick it manually, or do you want a random (computer generated) selection of a `lid`?

Comment: @NielsHenkens Just want a randomly generated lid, for eg for bid 23243 it is taking the 2nd lid for august 2021 and for 12145 it is taking the 3rd for May 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per `bid` and then per months and `bid` use [`DataFrameGroupBy.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#if necessary sorting
#df = df.sort_values(['bid','date'])

df['prev'] = df.groupby('bid').cumcount()
df1 = df.groupby(['bid', pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='date')], sort=False).sample(n=1)

print (df1)
     bid       lid       date  val1  val2  prev
1  23243  23435687 2021-08-12    34    55     1
2  23243  23218987 2021-09-17    54    43     2
5  12145  54789876 2021-05-20    33    44     2
6  12145  22898721 2021-08-13    27    88     3
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html), assume `date` column have `datetime64` dtype:

```
out = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.month, 'bid']).sample(n=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)

# Output
     bid       lid       date  val1  val2
0  12145  21113567 2021-05-11    89    76
1  12145  22898721 2021-08-13    27    88
2  23243  23435687 2021-08-12    34    55
3  23243  23218987 2021-09-17    54    43
```

Comment: thanks...nice solution.